# Does using numerous &nbsp; whitespace characters to center a line of text cause accessibility issues?

Tags: discussion, accessibility, mathjax, markdown

I'm quoting something that has a centered line of text in the source formatting (pg. 175 of the D&D 5e PHB). I initially used the MathJax display style environment $$ like so:

> Here’s how to determine a character’s total for a passive check:
>
> $$10 + \text{all modifiers that normally apply to the check}$$
>
> If the character has advantage on the check, add 5. For disadvantage, subtract 5.

```
>Here’s how to determine a character’s total for a passive check:
>
>$$10 + \text{all modifiers that normally apply to the check}$$
>
>If the character has advantage on the check, add 5. For disadvantage, subtract 5.
```

However, we generally prefer to avoid MathJax unless it is necessary (like the post contains math) since not all devices support it. So instead I've used the `&nbsp;` character to approximately center the line:

> Here’s how to determine a character’s total for a passive check:
>
> 10 + all modifiers that normally apply to the check
>
> If the character has advantage on the check, add 5. For disadvantage, subtract 5.

```
>Here’s how to determine a character’s total for a passive check:
>
>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10 + all modifiers that normally apply to the check
>
>If the character has advantage on the check, add 5. For disadvantage, subtract 5.
```

So while the markdown looks ridiculous, the output nicely matches the source formatting without using MathJax. Is this a better solution than using MathJax to center the line? Are there any accessibility related reasons I should avoid doing this as well?

Comment: No accessibility issue for screen readers; it's just a space.

Comment: Tested simple HTML: doesn't work. See answer below

Answer (score 9):

#### Irrespective of accessibility, it just isn't a good solution in general.

Checked my own post on my phone, and using `&nbsp;` doesn't work; it was aligned in the desktop browser I was using, but is going to be a crap shoot in other browsers and devices:

[image]

I guess there just isn’t a good way to center align text that isn’t MathJax.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason other than fidelity to the original typesetting that's pushing for centering? It seems to me like this would be one of those places where one can faithfully quote the *text* but not perfectly reproduce the typesetting without changing meaning. But I could be missing something?

Comment: @nitsua60 No, that's it. Real high stakes issue, I know.

Comment: Okay. (I mean, I'm with you on reproducing typesetting/appearance where feasible. Using italics for spells, bold-italic for things that are bold-italic in the source text, for example. Just wondered if there were something more here.)

Comment: As a side-observation: on D&DBeyond they don't center that line, but they do bold it =D https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#PassiveChecks

Comment: @nitsua60 Winner winner chicken dinner.

Comment: @nitsua60: [It is centered (and not bolded) in the PHB on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/using-ability-scores#PassiveChecks), just not in the Basic Rules.

Answer (score 7):

### Unless formatting is important, don't quote formatting

A general rule in quoting is, that formatting is not taken from a text unless it is important. Importance is usually only afforded to properties in the fontset, such as *italics*, **bolding** or CAPITAL LETTERS.

Text formatting on the page is usually not deemed essential in qupting, so a quote usually does not care for indentation or center format. The only exception in this is linebreaks, which often are deemed essential, and in some quotations are remarked with `//` or a similar orthographic solution in case the quote can't contain actual linebreaks.

### Center-alignment

#### MathJax

But if you absolutely must have center format, MathJax allows text with `$$\text{center}$$` for $$\text{center}$$

However, MathJax isn't *always* playing nice with screen readers, and such should be avoided for formatting only.

#### HTML doesn't work anymore

At *some* point, basic HTML was disabled from StackExchange, so that `<p align="center">test</p>`, usually a center-aligned text, is now rendered as follows:

test

In fact, the relevant HTML code isn't visible in the dev-console `F12`, and likewise the more verbose `<p style="text-align:center;">test</p>` wouldn't get parsed as formatting but stripped, just like `<div align="center">test</div>`:
[image: A side by side of the first two paragraphs of this section and its view in the dev-console]
[image: A side-by-side of the edit window of the above text and the dev-console parsing, highlighting the DIV portion and the parsed output when removing the {code}format.]

Comment: A very-limited subset of HTML _does_ work on the Stack. For the most part, I think the only HTML that works on Stack Exchange are the tags that replicate what you can do with markup, so there isn’t a lot of point to it. But as far as I know, that’s always been the case?

Comment: @KRyan indeed, but the number of working HTML for formating is down to bold and italics by now

Answer (score 6):

#### This is zero issue for screenreaders

A screenreader will just treat all those spaces as a space and move to the next text it has to read aloud, so it won’t cause any problems for those who rely on them.

#### Centering text is probably not an accessibility problem

Ignoring (for the moment) the “bug” [you found](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12282/4563), this is effectively centering. I have never received guidance that centered text is a problem for accessibility, and I have worked a fair amount on accessibility under the direction of accessibility experts (to wit: I would not claim to be one, myself). Accessibility is vast, and frankly it’s not a monolithic agreed-upon thing: there are a lot of suggestions, sometimes contradictory, about many details, once you get beyond the low-hanging fruit of headings, contrast, `alt` properties, and so on. But the general fact that most people find centering a useful way of “centering” some text is probably a good sign: it may very well *improve* accessibility, done well.

#### But of course, this isn’t *actually* centering the text

As you point out, narrower viewports cause text that is “centered” in this way to look awful, since the line wraps and the “centering” turns into what it actually is: an indent. Worse, this isn’t limited to narrow viewports: different fonts, different font sizes, etc. etc. If someone doesn’t have the Georgia font installed on their system, they’re going to see a different font, and that font’s relative widths will (probably) be different. If Stack Exchange decides to *change* the font in use—as they have in the past—then everyone’s “centering” will be off.

These problems aren’t really resolvable. Unless Stack Exchange offers proper centering, we don’t have it.

Comment: [Centered text](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/low-vision-a11y-tf/wiki/Supplemental_Guidance:_Text_Justification) can be an accessibility problem. It's usually fine for a line or two but centered paragraphs are harder to read than left justified ones.

Comment: @Laurel Oh, fair, didn’t think of entire paragraphs. Though I’d caution that a lot of the research on readability... leaves a lot to be desired. I haven’t investigated centering on this, per se, but a lot of the evidence for or against the “ragged right” vs. justified text is... poorly replicated, say.